# Looking for a pure c-version of math.h functions (no co-processor support)

Tags: c, libc, math.h, newlib, uclibc

I have to work with some (semi-)automatical verification software (CBMC [(link)](http://www.cprover.org/cbmc/)) which is statically working on C sources. Floating point is supported, but there are no definitions for all the mathematical functions. The attempt is to check, if it's possible to check numerical software with it.

So I need these functions. **I'm looking for some `math.h` definitions without co-processor use** (e.g. `sqrt`, `pow`, remainder, `tan`; `int`/`float`/`double`).

When I looked for it in a libc shipped with some linux distributions (maybe now eglibc), I always reached a point, where there are some processor-intrinsics meaning a hardware sqrt-function for example.

#### Part 1: searching for software implementations

What I need is a library supporting mathematical functions with the following characteristics:

- IEEE Floating-Point is supported, but a library operating purely on integers would be great too, maybe better.
- Correctness is a critical factor. (known bugs for special cases hidden in some sources are not that cool). The results should also be correct in terms of IEEE-754 (e.g. rules for sqrt).
- No use of co-processor calls. Pure software. C is preferred, but asm should be okay too.

Until now, I searched a bit for various libc implementations, especially ones regarding embedded systems. I think most of these libraries are targeting portability and size of compiled programs, but hard to tell if they are using processor-specific instructions.

- **[fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/) seems to have some pure-software definitions at a first glance. I will inspect this further. But there are some bugs mentioned in the sources (code isn't standard).
- **[newlib](http://www.sourceware.org/newlib/) seems to bring the same definitions (based on code of sun microsystems). But i can't say for sure at the moment if these software versions are alway used, so that there maybe some co-processor calls i don't see at the moment (see part 2).
- **[uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) seems to share the characteristic with newlib.

#### Part 2: understanding the structure of these implementations

- Could someone give me a short introduction to the structure of these math libraries. How do they dispatch the various versions (e.g. a specific co-processor)?
- And what are the meaning of these different prefixes in the filenames. `e_sqrt.c`, `k_sin`, `s_sin`?

I would be happy to hear about some libraries which **could** be useful for me. I would prefer to take a library as it comes, but when it is necessary, it is also possible to look for some single function implementations and build up a small library. I won't use all of the functions defined in math.h.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825221/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-javas-square-root-function) SO-posts are saying that the Java Math Implementation is/was based on **fdlibm** which sounds that this library is the way to go. Anyone with more information about this library I should know?

Seems that I have many possibilities including the following two:

1. **Use glibc and compile in software-mode**. The problem is, that I can't use any of the automatic system checking tools (in configure). I have to give all the information manually. Are there any flags to forbid the use of the fp-coprocessor and to forbid simd-operations? fp-without should be a start, then it is also using soft-float if it compiles. I expect that the compilation process is more or less dependent on a specific decision for a host (like arm...).
2. **Use fdlibm** (preferred at the moment). Problem: how do I link my programs to it? I need the non-libm functions like assert, but want to link against my fdlibm and not the system-libm which is installed (so -nodefaultlibs will forbid the use of assert).

Comment: i think you just need to pass some flag like use emulation during compilation

Comment: which x86 CPU doesn't have FPU for the last ~2 decades? If you're on x86, no reason for using software floating-point like that, unless you want higher precision. If you're on another architecture without FPU then obviously the math library for it must calculate those functions manually without intrinsic instructions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a full software implementation of IEEE-754 in [glibc/sysdeps/ieee754](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=sysdeps/ieee754;h=2a53a7b7468fe172dd21fe881dc43f8ff08e0520;hb=8ca52c6e3b2dc44a46c32d6a8e6a7f608915998f).  When you compile the library it might automatically substitute in an architecture specific version (eg `ia64/fpu/e_acosf.S`) of some function, but the entire library is implemented in software as well.