# Fast sqrt in Java at the expense of accuracy

Tags: java, performance, math, sqrt

I am looking for a fast square root implementation in Java for double values in the input range of [0, 2*10^12]. For any value in this range, the precision should be upto 5 decimal places. In other words, the result can differ from the `Math.sqrt()` method after 5 decimal places. However, this method needs to be much faster than `Math.sqrt()`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked anything on internet before asking here? What did you get?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Mostly C and assembly level hacks, most of which rely on a float value being 32 bit

Comment: Have you read [here](http://martin.ankerl.com/2009/01/05/approximation-of-sqrtx-in-java/)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes. However, the max error is 4%, which means it will make a huge difference when the input is 10^12.

Comment: There are alot of resources on the internet.... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69941/Best-Square-Root-Method-Algorithm-Function-Precisi and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623375/writing-your-own-square-root-function

Comment: @Paresh 4% the first time, if you read the **repeat the following line for more precision** and the explanation, you would have a better and fastest sqrt method. Still, it's up to you.

Comment: Have you profiled? Are you sure that sqrt is the bottleneck?

Sqrt is already pretty fast. I believe modern computers have dedicated hardware for it. If you want something faster, you'll probably have to descend to assembly level hacks.

Comment: If these methods still don't convince you, you can always call a C/C++ method from Java using [JNI](https://blogs.oracle.com/moonocean/entry/a_simple_example_of_jni)

Comment: @Dreamer78692 Thank you. As I mentioned above, in the first link, all the fast methods (1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 13, 14) either assume a 32 bit float, or are assembly level codes. Some of the methods in the wiki link are already implemented in the first link, and are slower. I have not adapted the Babylon method to Java double, and was hoping if someone knew a good implementation already.

Comment: Perhaps this is a long shot, but is the `sqrt()` necessary? Can you modify something somewhere else to deal with the squared value? Getting rid of a `sqrt` for the price of a `*` is always a good idea.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thank you! I did read the repeat part, and I have benchmarked it too. For getting the accuracy I need, I need to use that line 2 times atleast, which makes it *considerably* slower than Math.sqrt(). Which probably is in line with what Antimony mentions about sqrt already being fast.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 32 bit floats if you want 5 digits precision.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher Yes, that was my first thought too. I tried to remove the need for `sqrt()` but could not. I need to compare two values (say `a` and `b`), and consider them equal if they are within some `delta` of each other. However, if all I have is the squares of `a` and `b`, then I am unable to check if they are equal within that delta.

Comment: @starblue But I am working with double values. Or are you suggesting that I cast them to float? Is it a good idea to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe (without a benchmark to prove this wrong) that a pure Java implementation could me *much faster* than `Math.sqrt()`. Both the [Oracle JRE implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825221/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-javas-square-root-function) and the [OpenJDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/StrictMath.java#StrictMath) are native implementations.

Comment: I see! I was hoping that sacrificing accuracy might yield a faster method.

Comment: After JIT'ing, Java code can be as fast as native code. Not always, but it can be.

Comment: After some experimentation, it turns out, for the required accuracy, `Math.sqrt()` is the best option afterall!

Answer (score 13):

Once you give the code time to warm up. Math.sqrt() can be pretty fast

```
static double[] values = new double[500 * 1000];

public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) values[i] = i;

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = Math.sqrt(values[i]);
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;

        System.out.printf("Took %d ns to Math.sqrt on average%n", time / values.length);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took 20 ns to Math.sqrt on average
Took 22 ns to Math.sqrt on average
Took 9 ns to Math.sqrt on average
Took 9 ns to Math.sqrt on average
Took 9 ns to Math.sqrt on average
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
double d = 289358932.0;
double sqrt = Double.longBitsToDouble( ( ( Double.doubleToLongBits( d )-(1l<<52) )>>1 ) + ( 1l<<61 ) );
```

I haven't benchmarked it, but I'd expect it to be faster. The accuracy isn't extremely good, but try it out and see if it meets your needs. I think you can add an additional bias term `a` to the end of the expression to make it more accurate.

**EDIT:** You can drastically improve the accuracy by passing it through a round or two of Newton's method

```
double better = (sqrt + d/sqrt)/2.0;
double evenbetter = (better + d/better)/2.0;
```

The second pass gives you almost the exact value of the square root.

```
sqrt            17022.533813476562
better          17010.557763511835
evenbetter      17010.553547724947
Math.sqrt()     17010.553547724423
```

Comment: Thanks! It definitely is orders of magnitude faster if used without the Newton's method. But it is also very inaccurate. Each iteration of Newton's method seems to add an incredible amount of time: I suppose it may be due to division being expensive. 2 iterations gives the required accuracy, but makes it *slower* than `Math.sqrt()`. I guess I will have to live with `Math.sqrt()` after all!

Comment: Each iteration doubles the number of correct digits. `better` already has 7 digits accuracy.

Comment: @starblue I require 5 decimal places of accuracy, not 5 digits. `better` is accurate only upto 2 decimal places. `evenbetter` does the job but ends up being slower than `Math.sqrt()`.

Comment: I found this works for a good approximation, `Double.longBitsToDouble(((Double.doubleToRawLongBits(number) >> 32) + 1072632448 ) << 31);`
If you're working with number above 100,000 use this `1072679338` number over the `1072632448` because it will be more accurate.

Comment: In my own tests -- on average -- this appears to be the same speed as `Math.sqrt` (before the extra passes).

Comment: Instead of dividing by 2.0, multiply by 0.5 to make it tiny bit faster.

Comment: For sqrt of values ranging from 100 to 10000 the error is only about 1% by my quick debugging. Thanks! Very useful for quick distance metric in tracking application.
Is there an equivalent float version?