# Android: Chroma key performance for video

Tags: java, android, video, effect, chromakey

I have a [video stream](https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview/src/a4487b3e6a96?at=master) and like to apply a chroma key effect on it. I tried this [GPU library](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) but it is even slower as my own code:

```
public class ChromaKey {
    int[] pix;
    Bitmap bm;
    int picw, pich;
    int index, cur_pix, red2, green2, blue2;

    public Bitmap replaceIntervalColor(Bitmap bitmap,int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            picw = bitmap.getWidth();
            pich = bitmap.getHeight();
            if (pix == null)
            {
                pix = new int[picw * pich];
            }
            bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);

            double distance;

            for (int y = 0; y < pich; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < picw ; x++) {
                    index = y * picw + x;
                    cur_pix = pix[index];
                    red2 = (int)((cur_pix & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16); // Color.red(cur_pix);
                    green2 = (int)((cur_pix & 0x0000FF00) >>> 8); //Color.green(cur_pix);
                    blue2 = (int)(cur_pix & 0x000000FF); //Color.blue(cur_pix);
                    // faster Math.sqrt
                    // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13264441/956397
                    /* distance = Math.sqrt(
                            (red2 - red) * (red2 - red)
                                    + (green2 - green) * (green2 - green)
                                    + (blue2 - blue) * (blue2 - blue)
                    ); */
                    distance = Double.longBitsToDouble(((Double.doubleToRawLongBits( (red2 - red) * (red2 - red)
                            + (green2 - green) * (green2 - green)
                            + (blue2 - blue) * (blue2 - blue) ) >> 32) + 1072632448 ) << 31);

                    if (distance < 190)
                    {
                        pix[index] = Color.TRANSPARENT;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (bm == null)
            {
                bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(picw, pich, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
            }
            bm.setPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);
            return bm;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I improve the performance of this code?

I already moved all object creation out to reuse memory but it is still so slow on a high end tablet.

Comment: yo man. how to remove green color? should i set 255 in green position ?

Comment: @Peter yes (red=0, green=255, blue=0) if you have perfect green and perfect light. Otherwise you might need to adjust a little.

Comment: thank buddy for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you to move this operation to native library (C/C++). You can pass whole Bitmap object to native library function and modify content of Bitmap without copy pixels back and forth. Even optimization in  assembler can be applied.

Or more simpler try to optimize your code.

Comment: I did some simple performance measuring using `System.nanoTime()` and it turned out this code is fine. Problem was a bad network connection.