# Java: 32-bit fp implementation of Math.sqrt()

Tags: java, performance, math, 32-bit

The standard `Math.sqrt()` method seems pretty fast in Java already, but it has the inherent drawback that it is always going to involve 64-bit operations which does nothing but reduce speed when dealing with 32-bit `float` values.  Is it possible to do better with a custom method that uses a `float` as a parameter, performs 32-bit operations only, and returns a `float` as a result?

I saw:

[Fast sqrt in Java at the expense of accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263948/fast-sqrt-in-java-at-the-expense-of-accuracy)

and it did little more than reinforce the notion that Math.sqrt() is generally hard-to-beat.  I also saw:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69941/Best-Square-Root-Method-Algorithm-Function-Precisi

which showed me a bunch of interesting C++/ASM hacks that I am simply too ignorant to port directly to Java.  Though sqrt14 might be interesting as a part of a JNI call . . .

I also looked at Apache Commons FastMath, but it looks like that library defaults to the standard Math.sqrt() so no help there.  And then there's Yeppp!:

http://www.yeppp.info/

but I haven't bothered with that yet.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you'll get the speed benefit you hope you'd get

Comment: "64-bit operations ... does nothing but reduce speed when dealing with 32-bit float values" is a fallacy. In general, floating-point operations are always carried out in the precision of the FPU, and the overhead comes in widening and narrowing the `float` operands` to `double` to suit the FPU.

Comment: @EJP it's true for `sqrtsd`  vs `sqrtss`, but of course from a Java perspective you can't control that. As for the old-style FPU which works as you describe, it's essentially obsolete (and severely crippled in some Intel Atoms)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need nothing to speed up `sqrt` for 32-bit values. HotSpot JVM does it automatically for you.

JIT compiler is smart enough to recognize `f2d -> Math.sqrt() -> d2f` pattern and replace it with faster `sqrtss` CPU instruction instead of `sqrtsd`. [The source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/8b16790cd73a/src/cpu/x86/vm/x86.ad#l1654).

The benchmark:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class Sqrt {
    double d = Math.random();
    float f = (float) d;

    @Benchmark
    public double sqrtD() {
        return Math.sqrt(d);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public float sqrtF() {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(f);
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark    Mode  Cnt       Score      Error   Units
Sqrt.sqrtD  thrpt    5  145501,072 ± 2211,666  ops/ms
Sqrt.sqrtF  thrpt    5  223657,110 ± 2268,735  ops/ms
```

Comment: Interesting! Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to know JNI:

just write a minimal wrapper for `double sqrt(double)` and `float sqrt(float)` from C's standard library's `math.h` and compare performance.

Hint: you won't feel a difference unless you do a lot of square rooting, and then the performance advantage of using SIMD instructions to do multiple sqrts at once will most probably dominate the effects. You will need to get a memory-aligned array of the floating point values from Java, which can be quite hard, if you're using Java standard libraries.