# An alternative to Math class for Floats

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Will generate performance problems using functions of this style?:

```
*fun sqrt(x: Float) = Math.sqrt(x.toDouble()).toFloat()*

*fun cos(angle: Float) = Math.cos(angle.toDouble()).toFloat()*

*fun sin(angle: Float) = Math.sin(angle.toDouble()).toFloat()*
```

for using it so with Floats:

```
*sqrt(45.0f)*

*cos(1.58f)*

*sin(0.28f)*
```

instead of the much more verbose:

```
*Math.sqrt(45.0f.toDouble()).toFloat()*

*Math.cos(1.58f.toDouble()).toFloat()*

*Math.sin(0.28f.toDouble()).toFloat()*
```

Greetings and thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263948/fast-sqrt-in-java-at-the-expense-of-accuracy

Comment: It's not really a duplicate because in Java you can implicitly cast a Float to a Double but in Kotlin there is no implicit casting so interacting with the Java Math library gets real ugly real quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be NO *performance problem* in using the wrappers.

The performance may be slightly less due to calling those functions (they are statically dispatched, just like any utility methods).

If you use the wrappers in the **hot** code then you can inline them:

```
inline fun sqrt(x: Float) = Math.sqrt(x.toDouble()).toFloat()
```

For inlined functions the byte-code is No different to the one Java generates.

Comment: the JVM should notice these if they are a hot code-path and inline them for you, there is no gain from manually inlining them bigger than what hotspot would already decide.  On Android, maybe not.  So inline would help in the Android case, less on the JVM outside of Android case.

Comment: Agreed. The "hotter" the path, the less the gain

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem using the `Math` class. In earlier Android versions there was a class android.util.FloatMath which handles float arithmetic, but the common Math class is faster now and the class is deprecated.

> Historically these methods were faster than the equivalent double-based Math methods. On versions of Android with a JIT they became slower and have since been re-implemented to wrap calls to Math. Math should be used in preference.
>   All methods were removed from the public API in version 23.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/FloatMath.html

Answer (score 0):

As I understand performance, it is measured by the complexity of the algorithm.
An algorithm over an array of n elements, performing 1 operation on each, it is said to be of O(n) complexity.
The same algorithm complexity, performing 3 operations on each element is still O(n)
A fixed operation, like `.toFloat` or `.toDouble()` will not affect performance, since those are of O(1) complexity.

Comment: However there is not a 1:1 relationship between algorithm complexity and performance. An algo might still be the same O-notation order as another, but be slower in execution. For instance, there is only one operation on each, but op A takes longer than op B in the hardware layer for instance...

Comment: @RichardEriksson Yes, you are correct. In the real world 3 multiplications take 3 times the time of a single multiplication. But unless you are dealing with a lot of operations, the impact on the perceived time should be unnoticeable.

Comment: I believe this is not what was the question about

Answer (score 0):

In fact, trying:

```
var iniTemp = System.currentTimeMillis()
for (i in 1..10000000)
  sqrt(755.369f)
d((System.currentTimeMillis() - iniTemp).toString())
```

407 milisecs

and:

```
var iniTemp = System.currentTimeMillis()
for (i in 1..10000000)
  Math.sqrt(755.369f.toDouble()).toFloat()
d((System.currentTimeMillis() - iniTemp).toString())
```

317 milisecs

both in an older Nexus 7

Thanks

Comment: The only overhead is due to function calls. Use `inline` if you need exceptional performance in your hot code

Comment: for the measurements you use `measureTimeNano`

Comment: Adding inline, as recommended, 326 and 319 milisecs respectively.

Comment: well, that proves me right, doesn't it? If so, could you please mark my answer as helpful, please?