# What is accepted as the IEEE-754 correct result when computing this square root?

Tags: c++, matlab, math, floating-point, computer-science

I have an Newton-Raphson Square Root Algorithm I am using which computes the single-precision square root of an input value.  However using a testbench I input I found that certain input values don't converge to an answer which is closest to the actual square root.  When I say actual square root, I mean the result you would get with more precision than 32-bit IEEE-754.
As a result, I was wondering what is considered the correct value to be obtained when performing the square root in IEEE-754.  Some people on this forum have told me that the closest value is not necessarily the most correct, that is why I am asking.

When computing the square root of the single precision IEEE-754 32-bit value 0x3f7fffff, what is considered the correct result and why?

Furthermore, what is considered the correct result when compute the square root of 0x7F7FFFFF?

Comment: What result are you getting, and why do you suspect that it's wrong?

Comment: I would consider the correct result to be the IEEE-754 32-bit value whose square is the closest to 0x3f7fffff and 0x7F7FFFFF, respectively.

Comment: @John, I am getting the result of 1 = 0x3f800000

Comment: @StephenCanon, you know me better than that. This isn't homework. You've answered my questions in the past.

Comment: Basic information any request for help should always include: 1) What did you do? 2) What happened? 3) What did you expect to happen?  This is a universal principle, not unique to programming or even to technology

Comment: @Nemo, I want to just know what the accepted value is. I thought extraneous information isn't relevant.

Comment: @starbox: sorry, didn’t notice that you were asking the question.  I’ll post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0x3f7fffff` is `1.0 - u`, where `u = 2**-24`.  The Taylor Series for `sqrt(1 + x)` is:

```
sqrt(1 + x) = 1 + x/2 - x^2/8 + O(x^3)
```

If we plug `-u` in for `x`, we get:

```
sqrt(1 - u) = 1 - u/2 - u^2/8 - O(u^3)
```

The value `1 - u/2` is the exact halfway point between the two closest representable floating-point numbers, `1-u` and `1`; since the next term in the Taylor series is negative, the value of `sqrt(1 - u)` is just a tiny bit smaller, and so the result rounds down to `1 - u`.

`0x7f7fffff` is just `2**128*(1-u)`, so the mathematically exact square root is `2**64*(1 - u/2 - u^2/8 - ...)`, which rounds down to `2**64 * (1-u)`, as described above.

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying the rounding mode should not be round to nearest? it should be round down?

Comment: Sorry, I did the analysis for round-to-nearest only; it rounds down to `1 - u` in round-to-zero, round-to-minus-infinity, round-to-nearest, schoolbook rounding, and round-to-odd.  It rounds up to `1` in round-to-plus-infinity.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using the algorithm shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580859/how-to-fix-this-floating-point-square-root-algorithm, do you know a better one?

Comment: Does IEEE-754 say anything about whether a `sqrt` implementation *must* obtain such a value?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: yes, of course; `sqrt` is one of the fundamental operations that *shall* be correctly rounded in order to comply with the standard.

Comment: @StephenCanon: The only “to” rounding modes are “to nearest” and “to odd”. The others are all “toward”; e.g. one rounds in the direction toward zero, not all the way to zero. Although that would simplify implementation and improve speed. :-)