# how I can see how math.cos method in java calculate the square root?

Tags: java, math

I am not a genius mathematical scientist

but I'm trying  to see how sqrt , cos , sin ,... functions do the calculations

I opened the file strictMath.java 
which is inside 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\src.zip'

and that is what I found:

```
public static native double sin(double a);

public static native double cos(double a);

public static native double sqrt(double a);
```

I didnt see the code that each function use to calculate

so anyone can tell me how these functions work?

Comment: The Math.cos() method does not calculate the square root. Your title is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your solution in this post: [Where can I find the source code for Java's Square Root function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825221/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-javas-square-root-function)

In these cases, I recommend you to look directly at the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html