# Where is the source code for native java.lang.math methods in JDK 7?

Tags: java, native

Per the title, where is the source code for the native java.lang.math methods JDK 7?

Please don't point me to [Where to find source code for java.lang native methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods?rq=1) this only answers for JDK 6.

Oracle no longer appears to provide source for native methods at all.

I looked in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot but there are thousands and thousands of files with no obvious relationship to the package structure of the Java core so I cannot see any way to find the java.lang.Math methods.

Comment: Check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825221/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-javas-square-root-function

Comment: There is no native method in `java.lang.Math`.

Comment: @JBNizet as they mostly call into java.lang.StrictMath which has lot's of native functions...

Comment: StrictMath.c is there: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle-recommended reference implementation at OpenJDK has the native math methods in the following folder location:

```
jdk1.6\src\jdk\src\share\native\java\lang\fdlibm\src\*.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start the browsing from [StrictMath.c](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/native/java/lang/StrictMath.c)

For example, `asin` (redefined as `jasin`) is in [e_asin.c](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/e_asin.c)

Answer (score 0):

If just research, you can use OPENJDK7&8 instead.

you can download from [OpenJDK Project](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8).

**you can attach to eclipse.**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @amdixon: You need to be more thoughtful in applying the link-only answer deletion rule. It doesn't make sense to "include the essential parts" of a download link.

Comment: @JamesKPolk the user is asking which specific file some code is in. a download link for the entire jdk is therefore not informative. so yes essential parts should include the file location within the zip ( and probably the user should learn how to search )

Comment: Thanks for your hints