# Java Math sqrt source code

Tags: java, sqrt

I've been trying to get *sqrt* method's source code from the class ***Math***, I opened the class math from *src* folder, which contains the source code of Java.
I looked up the method and it turned out that it returns from the other method *sqrt* from the class ***StrictMath***. Again I open ***StrictMath***.
I was surprised that I didn't get the source code of the method itself but I found bunch of comments that are not helpful for me.
I am wondering how to get the source code of the method.

EDIT: I also looked up Oracle docs and didn't find anything. Same happened with Google.

Comment: If you're wondering how I found a post from all the way back in 2009... I just googled the exact text of this question's summary line. Did you try to search for this question before you posted it here?

Comment: You're talking like it has the answer in it. :)

Comment: That answer quotes documentation explaining why it's native, says what the library it uses is, and even copies the relevant part of that library. Not sure what more you'd want.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at its signature in StrictMath:

```
 public static native double More ...sqrt(double a);
```

You see the *native* keyword which indicates that [the method is probably not implemented in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for).

For more details see this: [Where can I find the source code for Java's Square Root function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825221/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-javas-square-root-function)

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) methods in `StrictMath` are `native`. That means they are implemented not in java but they are JNI calls.