# Is NaN a kind of runtime error in JAVA?

Tags: java

I'm doing the past paper of Java to prepare my Java examination.

A question in paper is giving some java code to you, and you need to evaluate the value & type of it, or find does it have any compilation error or runtime error.

Here is a code :

```
Math.sqrt(-2.0)
```

I try it in my java, but it only show  `NaN` , and no error message was show.

So, should I write it is runtime error or just write NaN in the value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean

Comment: I do not think this is duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

NaN means "not a number", and you got it because regular floating-point math doesn't support imaginary numbers. It's a placeholder that means "invalid value", but it's not an error at the language level.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error or exception. You can just consider it as a value of the result.

Answer (score 0):

No, The result you are getting is not a error at all. Function is returning value NaN means `Not a Number`

.

This function executes some underlying system algorithm and return value NaN.

> To help ensure portability of Java programs, the definitions of 
>   some of the numeric functions in this package require that they 
>   produce the same results as certain published algorithms. These 
>   algorithms are available from the well-known network library 
>   `netlib` as the package "Freely Distributable Math 
>   Library," `fdlibm`. These 
>   algorithms, which are written in the C programming language, are  then
>   to be understood as executed with all floating-point  operations
>   following the rules of Java floating-point arithmetic.

Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825221/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-javas-square-root-function) for more details.

**About**

*So, should I write it is runtime error or just write NaN in the value?*

It's up to you or requirement. If you are using this value in further calculations you should handle this case very carefully.
May be return zero if NaN could be a solution.

Comment: Returning zero when encountering a NaN is nearly always a terrible idea. Zero is a valid result.

Comment: yes @chrylis that's why I mentioned about as and if needed